# Properly Transfer And Process A Keyboard Event That Occurs On A Form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

The best example for my question is a ComboBox, when you click the drop down, a window comes up but if you type it still goes into the ComboBox. I have a similar setup to this. I have a specific event that triggers a form to show (it is now active - if it loses focus the form closes), the user should be able to type on that form and all the keyboard events should be passed to, and handled by, the TextBox. Shortcut keys would need to be processed as well. Trying to figure out the best was to do this. Would I use a NativeWindow and handle WndProc to relay messages to the TextBox? Seems like there should be a fairly simple way to do this.

I've gotten some implementations semi-working but not for specific keys such as a Backspace key or Ctrl + A.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Good question, I've done these kinds of things before but I usually hacked them into place in an ugly way.  I imagine you could SendMessage to the Textbox from within the form WndProc.  Good luck, I look forward to seeing how you solve it.

Comment: in your TextBox example, having the TextBox to focus when the window open is ok, no ? If the user wants to set focus elsewhere after, let it be... (or re-focus on TextBox after focus lost...)